# Pandas merge not working properly. Duplicating entries

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two large DataFrames.  Here is a toy example:

```
import pandas as pd

u_1 = pd.DataFrame({'cuid':[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3], 'data':[100, 100, 100,100,1,2,3,4]})
u_2 = pd.DataFrame({'cuid':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'extra':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

print(u_1)
print(u_2)

print(pd.merge(u_1, u_2, on='cuid', how='left'))
```

This produces the expected output:

```
   cuid  data
0     0   100
1     1   100
2     2   100
3     3   100
4     0     1
5     1     2
6     2     3
7     3     4
   cuid  extra
0     1      1
1     2      2
2     3      3
3     4      4
4     5      5
5     6      6
   cuid  data  extra
0     0   100    NaN
1     1   100      1
2     2   100      2
3     3   100      3
4     0     1    NaN
5     1     2      1
6     2     3      2
7     3     4      3
```

merging the two data sets along the cuid column using only the values from the left DataFrame (u_1) as the key.

When I take this to the larger DataFrames it breaks down and doubles the number of entries.  Here are the lines I'm running:

```
fmli_vars = test.copy().reset_index()
temp = memi_vars.loc[idx[:, 1], 'hrly_wge'].reset_index()

fmli_vars = pd.merge(fmli_vars, temp, how='left', on='cuid')
```

Indeed they do line up before the merge over at least part of the key:

```
#test if they line up at all
print fmli_vars.['cuid'].isin(temp['cuid']).describe()

count      184297
mean     0.680787
std      0.466173
min         False
25%             0
50%             1
75%             1
max          True
Name: cuid, dtype: object
```

However, the number of observations doubles.  Here is the output of `fmli_vars['quarters_present'].describe()` both before and after:

```
count    436339.000000
mean          4.813072
std           0.389854
min           4.000000
25%           5.000000
50%           5.000000
75%           5.000000
max           5.000000
Name: quarters_present, dtype: float64

count    912755.000000
mean          4.826985
std           0.378260
min           4.000000
25%           5.000000
50%           5.000000
75%           5.000000
max           5.000000
Name: quarters_present, dtype: float64
```

It's my impression that a left merge should not change the number of entries?  Can anyone explain what I'm missing?  Why is this happening!?

Comment: Do you have any duplicates in the 'cuid' column in the right dataframe?

Comment: Another question do you `NaN` values in 'cuid' ?

Comment: Yes!  There are duplicate 'cuid' entries!  Thanks for pointing that out.  I'll get back about whether fixing that helps.